# 2nd Exchange Server 2013

Tags: windows, exchange

I was going to add a 2nd Exchange server to our single forest domain. I set the Windows server up, installed Exchange but never configured anything for it. I have decided not to pursue this. If I uninstall Exchange, will that have any consequences? The original exchange server does see that it exists.

Comment: Hi, it's been a while, is there any update? If your problem has been fixed, you could mark the best answer or share your solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I uninstall Exchange, will that have any consequences?

No. Simply uninstall Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

If there are some required mailboxes/public folders on the 2nd server, make sure they are moved to the first server.

After that, as **joeqwerty** said, just perform uninstall of your Exchange server. You could uninstall the 2nd server via Control Panel or unattended mode(**Setup /mode:uninstall /IAcceptExchangeServerLicenseTerms**):

[image]

If you encounter the error in the following screenshot, this guidance may be helpful: **[How to Uninstall Exchange 2013 on Server 2012](https://blog.thirdechelon.org/2014/05/how-to-uninstall-exchange-2013-on-server-2012/)**

[image]